# Hive: Cant perform union query with limit

Tags: sql, hive, union, hiveql, hive-query

I am trying to run a union all query in hive

```
select * from tabName where col1='val1' and col2 = 'val2' limit 10 union all select * from tabName where col1='val1' and col2 = 'val3' limit 10;
```

but i get

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:105 missing EOF at 'union' near '10'
```

I also tried

```
( select * from tabName where col1='val1' and col2 = 'val2' limit 10 ) as a union all ( select * from tabName where col1='val1' and col2 = 'val3' limit 10 ) as b;
```

but i got

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:109 missing EOF at 'as' near ')'
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use select from subquery:

```
select * from
( select * from tabName where col1='val1' and col2 = 'val2' limit 10 ) a 
union all 
select * from
( select * from tabName where col1='val1' and col2 = 'val3' limit 10 ) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer another way using with clause:

```sql
with query1 as (
  select *
  from tabName
  where col1 = 'val1' and col2 = 'val2'
  limit 10
),
query2 as (
  select *
  from tabName
  where col1 = 'val1' and col3 = 'val3'
  limit 10
)
select * from query1
union all
select * from query2
```